# How do I ignore empty JSON arrays when deserializing POCO classes?

Tags: json, hl7-fhir

I am using the NuGet package Hl7.Fhir.STU3 to save me from having to create all the POCO classes.

The Json returned from the NHS FHIR Server is (I've removed a huge chunk to make it easier to read):

```
{
"id": "000049660991",
"meta": {
    "versionId": "3",
    "profile": [
        "https://fhir.nhs.uk/STU3/StructureDefinition/eRS-ReferralRequest-1"
    ]
},
"resourceType": "ReferralRequest",
"supportingInfo": [],
"intent": "plan"
```

}

The problem comes when I try to deserialize it as the "supportingInfo" element contains an empty array so I receive the following error (ignore the position):

```
Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.DeserializationFailedException: 'One or more errors occurred. (An array needs to have at least one element. At line 1, position 2445.)'
```

Is there a way to ignore empty arrays?

Comment: That's actually a non-conformant FHIR instance.  FHIR rules say that if an element is going to be included in an instance, it SHALL have a descendant value.  So erroring is actually a reasonable behavior (though a better error message would be nice).

Comment: Could you add the code you use for parsing the data? I've tried to reproduce using the 4.3.0 version of the library, but my FhirJsonParser just ignores the empty array.